# how to update field the following trigger and what is the meaning of that error

Tags: apex, trigger, update

```
trigger CTC_Update on Appraisal__c (before insert) {
    List<appointment__c> AppList = New List<appointment__c>();
    Set<Id> AppointIds = New Set<Id>();

    For(Appraisal__c A : Trigger.New)
    {
        AppointIds.Add(A.ApplicantName__c);
    }

    List<appointment__c> AppointList = [Select Id,Current_CTC__c from appointment__c where id =: AppointIds];

    For(Appraisal__c Aps : Trigger.New)
    {
        appointment__c A = new appointment__c();

        For(appointment__c App : AppointList)
        {
            IF(Aps.ApplicantName__c == App.ID)
            {
                A.Id = App.Id;

                IF(Aps.amount_of_Increment__c != 0 || Aps.amount_of_Increment__c != NULL)
                {
                    A.Current_CTC__c = App.Current_CTC__c + Aps.amount_of_Increment__c ;
                }
                IF(Aps.Increment_Percentage__c != 0 || Aps.Increment_Percentage__c != NULL)
                {
                    A.Current_CTC__c = App.Current_CTC__c + (App.Current_CTC__c * Aps.Increment_Percentage__c);
                }
            }
            AppList.Add(A);
        }
    }

    IF(AppList != NULL)
    {
        Update AppList;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving ?

Comment: "required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'trigger'" this error is showing

Comment: I can't see you are using trigger.New here? what is the relationship between `appointment__c` and `Appraisal__c` ?

Comment: You must be updating some appraisal records in this trigger. So where is your trigger.new in the code ? You have not provided any record ids in your code which needs to be updated. Just writing Appraisal__c aps;  will not fetch any records in you trigger.

Comment: couldn't get u can u explain the code please

Comment: one simple question what is your business goal ?

Comment: for recruitment purpose but in this case There are 2 objects 1. appointment (currentCTC Field) & 
       2. appraisal.(increment% ,
       increment amount fields)
whenever either increment% or incrementamount  is filled the incremented value  will be updatted to currentCTC field.
For the above trigger "required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'trigger' error is showing.suggest"

Comment: I suggest visit trailhead and learn how to use trigger https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger the code upon the update of fields on Appraisal object then have your code trigger on the same object. You can try the below trigger.

```
 Trigger CtcUpdate on Appraisal__c(After Insert , After Update)
 {
    List<Appointment__c> AppList = New List<Appointment__c>();
    Set<Id> AppointIds = New Set<Id>();

    For(Appraisal__c A : Trigger.New)
    {
        AppointIds.Add(A.Appointment__c);
    }

    List<Appointment__c> AppointList = [Select Id,Current_CTC__c from Appointment__c where id =: AppointIds];

    For(Appraisal__c Aps : Trigger.New)
    {
        Appointment__c A = new Appointment__c();

        For(Appointment__c App : AppointList)
        {
            IF(Aps.Appointment__c == App.ID)
            {
                A.Id = App.Id;

                IF(Aps.amount_of_Increment__c != NULL)
                {
                    A.Current_CTC__c = App.Current_CTC__c + Aps.amount_of_Increment__c ;
                }
                IF(Aps.Increment_Percentage__c != NULL)
                {
                    A.Current_CTC__c = App.Current_CTC__c + (App.Current_CTC__c * Aps.Increment_Percentage__c);
                }
            }
            AppList.Add(A);
        }
    }

    IF(AppList != NULL)
    {
        Update AppList;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.